# Enable access for Assistive Devices through a popup

Tags: cocoa, accessibility-api

Is there a way to ask to enable access for assistive device in a popup windows (NSAlert like) with a button directly in the popup window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, users have to open the System Preferences to enable this.

You can provide a button to navigate to the right System Preference page though:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/System/Library/PreferencePanes/UniversalAccessPref.prefPane"];
```

Comment: That was my second option. If it's the only possible one, i'll go for it. Thx